# Spring 3.2 disable @Cacheable during unit tests

Tags: hibernate, testng, ehcache, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing a problem with my unit tests. I currently use ehcache whith spring 3.2 (@Cacheable) everything works well but i would like to disable the cache during my unit tests.

So in src/test/resources/ehcache.xml i wrote :

```
<cache name="myCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="1"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       timeToLiveSeconds="0"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       maxElementsOnDisk="0"
       diskPersistent="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="0"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

but the cache still working ! Is anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You may try to evict from the secondary cache as one option. (just before running your unit test. )

Answer (score 0):

Spring profile is done for that purpose. See documentation [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Define a profile "test" in your cache manager bean (`<bean profile="test" ... />`) or upper and activate or not this profile with annotation `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

If your problem persists, verify that the context which defines the cache is the root context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I don't know what write to disable the cache even if i don't declare cache manager in my applicationContextTest.xml cache still enabled

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. Could you give spring context configuration file or class and Entity class plesae ?

Comment: To disable ehcache, just add this property/value : `net.sf.ehcache.disabled=true`. You can do this in code in `@BeforeClass` annotated method with `System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.disabled", Boolean.TRUE.toString());`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, adding your code didn't work, so to resolve the problem i added @CacheEvict on appropriate methods. Thanks again for your help